If a combination of generators of the ideal of a smooth submanifold vanish, then the coefficients can be taken to be antisymmetric
Execuse me the word salad title, but I have no idea how to say this concisely. Suppose that $M$ is a smooth $m$ dimensional manifold, and $\Sigma$ is a smooth submanifold of codimension $0<n<m$. Let $x\in\Sigma$ be a generic point and since in this question I am interested only in local stuff, suppose that we are working in an arbitrarily small neighborhood (in $M$) of $x$.
Let $F^1,\dots,F^n$ be a set of smooth functions whose zero locus is $\Sigma$ and the differentials $dF^i$ are linearly independent at $\Sigma$.
It is then well-known that any function $f$ vanishing on $\Sigma$ can be written as $$ f=\sum_i g_i F^i, $$ for some functions $g_i$.
There is then apparantly a theorem as follows:
Theorem: Suppose there are smooth functions $R_1,\dots,R_n$ such that $$ 0=\sum_i R_i F^i $$holds everywhere. Then $R_i$ vanish on $\Sigma$, furthermore we can write $$ R_i=\sum_j Q_{ij}F^j, $$ where the coefficients $Q_{ij}$ are smooth functions that can be taken to be antisymmetric in $ij$.
I only have problems with the final statement. The regularity conditions on $F^i$ mean that we can choose a coordinate system $(x^1,\dots,x^{m-n},y^1,\dots,y^n)$ such that $y^i = F^i$. Then differentiating $0=\sum_i R_i y^i$ with respect to $y^j$ gives $$ 0=\sum_i\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial y^j}y^i+R_j, $$ and taking $y=0$ gives $$ R_i(x,0)=0, $$ so the $R_i$ vanish along $\Sigma$, and thus because the ideal of $\Sigma$ is generated by the $F^i=y^i$, there are coefficients $$ Q_{ij} $$ such that $$ R_i = \sum_j Q_{ij}y^j.$$ Then differentiating $\sum_{ij}Q_{ij}y^iy^j=0$ twice we get $$ 0=Q_{ij}+Q_{ji}+\text{terms homogeneous in }y^k, $$ so setting $y=0$ again we get $$ Q_{ij}(x,0)+Q_{ji}(x,0)=0, $$ so the $Q_{ij}$ are skew-symmetric along $\Sigma$.
But I was unable to prove that the $Q_{ij}$ can be chosen such that the skew-symmetry holds away from $\Sigma$ as well. Apparently this is elementary because every text I have seen to state this theorem, it is always left as an exercise to the reader, but I can't seem to be able to figure this out.
Question: How to prove the antisymmetry conditions in the Theorem?

Let (using notation in the OP) $$ Q_{ij}(x,y):=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\partial R_j}{\partial y^i}(x,ty)-\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial y^j}(x,ty)\right)t\,\mathrm{d}t. $$
Then $R_i(x,y)=\sum_jQ_{ij}(x,y)y^j$.
I got this from the homotopy operator for the Koszul resolution of the surface $y^i=0$ (see e.g. Henneaux and Teitelboim: Quantization of Gauge Systems, 9.A.2), and I would hardly consider this elementary, though one could come up with this integral in a trial-end-error way I guess. Still, am a bit surprised textbooks put this as an exercise for the reader...
